# What rewards will be in highest level Jannah?

Tags: jannah, reward

I would like to know rewards you will get if you enter highest level Jannah aka Jannatul-Firdaws.  I couldn't find much about highest level Jannah.  Most people know what a lowest level person in Jannah will get but I couldn't find anything on highest level Jannah.  I know prophet Musa(A.S) asked Allah about who will get highest level jannah but I think Allah said it is no eye seen, no ear heard, no heart can imagine or something like that.  Please remember I am not asking who will get highest level Jannah, I am asking what kind of rewards they will get if you enter Jannatul Firdaws, please answer from Quran and hadiths.

Answer (score 1):

In [Ayah 17 of Surat Assajdah](https://quran.com/32/17?translations=20), we read:

> فَلَا تَعْلَمُ نَفْسٌ مَّا أُخْفِيَ لَهُم مِّن قُرَّةِ أَعْيُنٍ جَزَاءً بِمَا كَانُوا يَعْمَلُونَ
>
> Fala taAAlamu nafsun ma okhfiya lahum min qurrati aAAyunin jazaan bima kanoo yaAAmaloon
>
> No soul knoweth what is kept hid for them of joy, as a reward for what they used to do.